# IOS - Objective C - How do I remove Tableview Menu from my Login View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

In my iOS Project, there is a login ViewController that sends the user to a **TabViewController** if he has the right credentials.

This TabViewController has 5 tabs, the fifth one is for Logout, which send the user back to the Login ViewController, and of course clears out the already filled credentials of the user.

[image]

My problem is that i have the menu of the TableView shown in my Login page.
How to i get rid of this menu in my Login ViewController page ?

I use Xcode6 & Objective-C

if you need any further explanations/source code of my problem, feel free to ask.

**note:**

In the beginning, I mean when the Login ViewController is first shown to the user, the menu doesn't show.

[image]

Comment: I guess you are asking to hide tabbar view in login page?

Comment: Your problem is somewhere in the phrase "send the user to the login page again".  What code are you using to do that?

Comment: @sujay : Yes I think

Comment: @philip : I don't use any code , i just created a link in my storyboard between the tabsView and the loginViewcontroller  ( the nature of the rlationship segue is : view controllers )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, it's not the optimal solution but it worked for me:

what I did is :

**1- I deleted the Tab Bar Item from my Login ViewController**

**2- I inserted a logout button in my table view screens**

**3- I added segues from my Table view screens to the login screen in my storyboard.**

This way if the user clicks on the logout button , he will be directed to the login screen & cannot go back where he was unless he enters his credentials.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that whole UI architecture of your app is based on the `UITabBarController`. However it is not very good practice in your case. I would like to suggest you add separate modal controller for presenting login page.

Comment: i tried that , but when i wanted to add a logout solution to my tabsViewcontrollers, i didn't know how as we can't add buttons to tabsViewcontrollers, so i decided to add a tabBar item to my loginViewController and make segue with a relationship called ( view controllers)  between the loginviewController and the tabsViewcontrollers

Comment: If you actually don't need tab bar at login page, you can make modal segue from login controller to tab bar controller

Comment: i don't need a tabBar at my login page, so if i make a modal segue from login controller to tab bar controller, how can i then add a logout button in my tab bar controller ? because the only way i know is to add a tab bar item into it !

Comment: Maybe `-setItems:animated:` will be useful?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
self.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: 1 point for easiest method. But your code will useful only when their will be no tab bar item in login page.

Comment: yes, actually i have a tabBar item in my login page, so i guess this answer dosen't help solve the problem in my case

Comment: @Sujay : what i f i remove the tabBar item from my login page ? how can I make the connection between the Tabs View Controller and the loginViewController ? because apparently i can't add buttons in a " Tabs View Controller " , the only way i can make connection to a view controller is by using this tabBar item , or am I wrong ?

Comment: @samouray, yes you can. Create a `UITabbarController` as root view controller than you manage tab bar items as per condition I mean remove/ add tab bar item, **check my answer**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a storybaord I have the given solution
I created a sample application and tried replicating your issue, so here's the look at my storyboard

[image: StoryBoard]

The way i designed it i have a separate login view controller and two view controller (Menu List and Logout) which are embedded in a tabbar controller.

If you're new to storyboard then embedding viewControllers with tabbarController is pretty much straight forward, you select the view controller first and then go to the editors menu in Xcode

[image: Embedding View Controllers with TabbarController]

Alright now coming back to business, code which i added on the IBAction of the login screen button is given below where **MainTabbar** is the storyboardID of the TabMaster controller

```
 AppDelegate *appdel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
 UIStoryboard *storyBoard = appdel.window.rootViewController.storyboard;

TabMasterController *tabController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
@"MainTabbar"];
[appdel.window setRootViewController:tabController];
```

When i executed the application everything was OK and I was able to see the tabbar items after I hit the action button on login screen

[image: TabBar Items]

Now its time to write some code for the logout tabbar item, so I selected the view controller assigned to the Main tabbar controller and added the delegate mentod of [UITabbarController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/) which looks some what like this

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
// Since i have two tabbar items 1 generally means logout in my case
if (tabBarController.selectedIndex ==1) {
    AppDelegate *appdel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = appdel.window.rootViewController.storyboard;

    ViewController *tabController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
                                     @"LoginVC"];
    [appdel.window setRootViewController:tabController];
}
}
```

**LoginVC** is the storyboardID of the Login View controller

After adding the above code when i used to tap on the logout tabbar item I was able to go back to the login screen in my storyboard.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for the effort, I appreciate your answer but I already solved the problem by deleting the TabBarItem from my login page and just adding a "LOGOUT" button everywhere in my application, i know,  it's the easy way but i didn't have any answer and didn't want to lose anymore time on the issue

Comment: @samouray: No worries am glad that you were able to resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks man, i really appreciate your effort , if only i was able to give you +10 for that :D

Comment: Well you may accept my answer in that case @samouray :)

Comment: Oh great @samouray :)

Answer (score 0):

Either you can add tab bar item programmatically or you can add in `storyboard`
If programmatically then add like

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myContactsController],
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.searchController], 
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.registrationController], 
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginController], nil];
```

Set `tabbarController` as initial view controller in `storyboard`

After checking login credential, **On success**

```
// to get list of current tab bar items
NSMutableArray *tbViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];

// to remove tab bar items using index value
[tbViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:3];
[tbViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:2];

// to add tab bar items
[tbViewControllers addObject:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myProfileController]];
[tbViewControllers addObject:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.logoutController]];

// to set pre selected tab bar item
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=2;

// set array items in tab bar
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tbViewControllers];
```